# Google Spreadsheets: Group rows by equal cell and set background color for these rows

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Using Google Spreadsheets: I need to Group rows by equal cell value and set background color for these rows.

I need to alternate two color, one for each match.

Here an editable spreadsheet with the real example. The key value is the cell on column B:title (KEY)

Editable file:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1klXxhhdgaazGc-secQPZfwdNijLUK6OVOQUxdU-scQU/edit?usp=sharing

Capture:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added solution to your [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1klXxhhdgaazGc-secQPZfwdNijLUK6OVOQUxdU-scQU/edit#gid=403719919):

***Helper Column formula***:

```
=scan(;B2:index(B:B;match(2;1/(A:A<>"")));lambda(a;c;if(c<>offset(c;-1;);a+1;a)))
```

***Conditional formatting custom_formula***:

Apply to range: `A2:C`

```
=isodd($D2)
=iseven($D2)*len($D2)
```

[image]